Why event is not triggered correctly?
I have a Maui application that uses Entity Framework (EF) SQLite with the Unit of Work pattern. I want to trigger an event whenever data is added, updated, or deleted, and the changes are saved. This event should call a method in the sync agent to start a local-remote sync. However, the breakpoint for this event is not being hit. What am I doing wrong?
/// <summary>
/// Sync agent. It's the sync orchestrator
/// Knows both the Sync Server provider and the Sync Client provider.
/// </summary>
public class SyncAgent
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public SyncAgent(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public async Task SynchronizeAsync()
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("Test saved change");
        // get syncronizable entities
        //var result = await _unitOfWork.GetSyncableItemsAsync();
    }
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public event EventHandler EntitySaved;

    public async Task SaveChangesAsync() 
    {
        // saving stuff
        // ...

        // fire event
        EntitySaved?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

public class RemoteSyncHandler
{
    private readonly SyncAgent _syncAgent;

    public RemoteSyncHandler(SyncAgent syncAgent)
    {
        _syncAgent = syncAgent;
    }

    public void OnChangesSaved(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _syncAgent.SynchronizeAsync().SafeFireAndForget();
    }
}

// in the the Ioc
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
services.AddScoped<SyncAgent>();

services.AddScoped<RemoteSyncHandler>(provider =>
{
    var handler = new RemoteSyncHandler(provider.GetRequiredService<SyncAgent>());
    var unitOfWork = provider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>();

    // Subscribe to the ChangesSaved event
    unitOfWork.EntitySaved += handler.OnChangesSaved;

    return handler;
});

The Unit of Work is injected into ViewModels to perform CRUD operations. With the current implementation, I attempted to connect the Unit of Work and the sync agent without properly initializing the sync agent, as follows:
var uow = new UnitOfWork();
var syncAgent = new SyncAgent(uow);
uow.EntitySaved += syncAgent.OnChangesSaved;

What am I doing wrong?
What are some alternative ways to notify the sync agent to start synchronization? I also want the synchronization process to run in the background without blocking the UI like event and safefireandforget.

You are not calling await syncAgent.SaveChangesAsync();

SyncAgent does not have SaveChangesAsync

I can rephrase, you are not calling await UOW.SaveChangesAsync.

UnitOfWork which has repositories injected into ViewModels where it is called but that part is irrelevant.

SyncAgent doesn't have an OnChangesSaved method as far as you've shown us, so I don't know how uow.EntitySaved += syncAgent.OnChangesSaved; would compile...

My idea was to decouple UnitOfWork and SyncAgent therefore I created the handler so the uow would trigger the handler with event and the handler calles the SynchronizeAsync().
